# How to layer a distinct alpha channel animation on top of video?

Tags: ios, animation, video, avfoundation

I'm developing an iphone app and am having issues with the AVFoundation API; I'm used to lots of image manipulation, and just kind of figured I would have access to an image buffer; but the video API is quite different.

I want to take a 30 frame/sec animation which is generated as PNGs with transparency channel, and overlay it onto an arbitrary number of video clips composited inside of a AVMutableComposition.

I figured that the AVMutableVideoComposition would be a good way to go about it; but as it turns out, the animation tool, AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool, requires a special kind of CALayer animation. It supports an animation with basic stuff like a spatial transform, scaling, fading, etc -- but my animation is already complete as a series of PNGS.

Is this possible with AVFoundation? If so, what is the recommended process?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with `UIImageView` and `animationImages`:

```
UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
NSMutableArray *animationImages = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    [animationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d", i]]];
}
anImageView.animationImages = animationImages;
anImageView.animationDuration = 500/30;
```

Comment: That's OK for the PNG sequence. Sorry, I wasn't clear with my intentions, but the goal is to export a video composite of the two. I can play them back just fine, but I need to save them at a reasonable file size, and for shareability it needs to be a standard asset format (video).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [AVVideoCompositing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVVideoCompositing_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVVideoCompositing/startVideoCompositionRequest:) protocol along with [AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest). Use `[AVAsynchronousVideoCompositionRequest sourceFrameByTrackID:]` to get the `CVPixelBufferRef` for the video frame. Then Create a `CIImage` with the appropriate png based on the timing you want. Then render the video frame onto a `GL_TEXTURE`, render the `CIImage` to a `GL_TEXTURE`, then draw these all into your destination `CVPixelBufferRef` and you should get the effect you are looking for.

Something Like:

```
CVPixelBufferRef foregroundPixelBuffer;
CIImage *appropriatePNG = [CIImage imageWithURL:pngURL];
[someCIContext render:appropriatePNG toCVPixelBuffer:foregroundPixelBuffer]

CVPixelBufferRef backgroundPixelBuffer = [asynchronousVideoRequest sourceFrameByTrackID:theTrackID];

//... GL Code for rendering using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to comp each set of input images (background and foreground) down to a single pixel buffer and then encode those buffers into a H.264 video a frame at a time. Just be aware that this will not be super fast since there is a lot of memory writing and encoding time to create the H.264. You can have a look at [AVRender](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVRender) to see a working example of the approach described here. If you would like to roll your own impl then take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) which includes source code that can help you get started.